# Bounds on the probability of simultaneous events using "Bonferroni's inequality"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In George Casilla and Roger Berger's "Statistical Inference" (2nd ed.), the authors introduce what they call a special case of "Bonferroni's inequality" as
\begin{equation}
P(A\cap B) \geq P(A)+ P(B) - 1.\tag{1}
\end{equation}
The authors also introduce "Boole's inequality" as
\begin{equation}
P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A_{i})\text{ for any sets $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots$}.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
It is also given from the authors that
\begin{equation}
P(A^{c}) = 1-P(A)\quad (\text{$P(A)=1-P(A^{c})$} ).\tag{3}
\end{equation}
By combining (1)-(3) above, noting how it is known that
\begin{equation}
P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_{i})\text{ for any sets $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots,A_{n}$},
\end{equation}
I have stumbled upon the following (in the case of only two arbitrary events):
\begin{equation}
P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B)-1.
\end{equation}
Can someone check my reason to see if I have erroneously reasoned to the above expression? If so, could someone point out where my reason went wrong. Thank you!

**My reasoning is as follows:**

From (1),
\begin{equation}
P(A)+P(B)-1 \leq P(A\cap B).
\end{equation}
Since
\begin{alignat}{1}
P(A\cap B) &= 1-P((A\cap B)^{c})\\
&= 1-P(A^{c}\cup B^{c})
\end{alignat}
by De Morgan's, (2) and (3) yield
\begin{alignat}{1}
P(A\cap B) &= 1-P(A^{c}\cup B^{c})\\
&\leq 1-P(A^{c})-P(B^{c}) \\
&= 1-(1-P(A))-(1-P(B)) \\
&= P(A)+P(B) - 1.
\end{alignat}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
P(A) +P(B)-1 \leq P(A\cap B) \leq P(A)+P(B)-1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
P(A\cap B) = P(A) + P(B) -1.
\end{equation}

Comment: In the line of $1-P(A^c\cup B^c) \leq 1-P(A^c)-P(B^c)$, we have $P(A^c\cup B^c)\leq P(A^c)+P(B^c)$, so the inequality must be reversed.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!